# Простое многопоточное приложение с использованием мьютекса

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi, mutex

Начал поверхностно изучать многопоточность. Написал небольшой код.

Функция для каждого потока:

```
DWORD WINAPI increment(CONST LPVOID lpParam)
{
    CONST HANDLE hMutex = (CONST HANDLE)lpParam;
    while (testMutex < testMax)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        testMutex++;
        if(testMutex<testMax)
            std::cout << testMutex << std::endl;
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    }
    ExitThread(0);
}
```

И сама функция создания потоков:

```
void createMutexAndThread()
{
    HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    HANDLE hThreads[500];
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        hThreads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &increment, hMutex, 0, NULL);
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreads[0], INFINITE);
    //WaitForMultipleObjects(64, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);

    std::cout << "1\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);
    }

}
```

Мьютекс разблокируется на функции `ReleaseMutex(...)`, но на какой строке в функции `increment` мьютекс будет блокироваться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция WaitForSingleObject ожидает освобождения мютекса и занимает его сама.